# How to do strict substring search when text contains '.'?

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

I have few rows that contain text `"bot.xx"` and few rows contains `"botris","botmax"` I want to exclude all rows from my data frame that has bot.01, bot.12 and so on but i want to keep rows which has "botris" , "botmax" or anything that doesnt have period after string bot

i am using `df = df[~df['coulmn'].str.contains('bot.')]`

this is removing bot.01 bot.XX and botris and botmax as well.

Comment: are the text in differennt columns or the same. Please show a workable sample of your data

Comment: Try escaping the period? ie `df[~df['coulmn'].str.contains('bot\.')]`

Comment: thanks @Chris yes it worked ,

Comment: It was in one column only thank you

Answer (score 0):

It's because it thinks it's regex, so try:

```
df[~df['coulmn'].str.contains('bot\.')]
```

Or:

```
df[~df['coulmn'].str.contains('bot.', regex=False)]
```